# Scala capture group using regex

Tags: regex, string, scala, capturing-group

Let's say I have this code:

```
val string = "one493two483three"
val pattern = """two(\d+)three""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).foreach(println)
```

I expected `findAllIn` to only return `483`, but instead, it returned `two483three`. I know I could use `unapply` to extract only that part, but I'd have to have a pattern for the entire string, something like:

```
 val pattern = """one.*two(\d+)three""".r
 val pattern(aMatch) = string
 println(aMatch) // prints 483
```

Is there another way of achieving this, without using the classes from `java.util` directly, and without using unapply?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can access `group(1)` of each match:

```
val string = "one493two483three"
val pattern = """two(\d+)three""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
   m => println(m.group(1))
}
```

This prints `"483"` ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Ooyti)).

---

#### The lookaround option

Depending on the complexity of the pattern, you can also use lookarounds to *only* match the portion you want. It'll look something like this:

```
val string = "one493two483three"
val pattern = """(?<=two)\d+(?=three)""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).foreach(println)
```

The above also prints `"483"` ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/oPV2l)).

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: You can also use `pattern.findAllMatchIn(string).foreach...` instead

Answer (score 52):

```
val string = "one493two483three"
val pattern = """.*two(\d+)three.*""".r

string match {
  case pattern(a483) => println(a483) //matched group(1) assigned to variable a483
  case _ => // no match
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest way by far. You use the regex object ("pattern") in a match/case and extracts the group into the variable a483.
The problem withthis case is that the pattern should have wildcards on both sides:
val pattern = """.*two(\d+)three.*""".r

Comment: Yes. I don't think the above is immediately clear, but once you understand that it's assigning the digit matching group to the variable 'a483', then it makes more sense. Perhaps rewrite in a clearer fashion ?

Comment: This is the scala way with regex. For people don't understand the magic behind this answer, try search "scala regex extractor" or "scala unapply regex" etc.

Comment: the semantics is unclear.  is this the first, last, or a random match from the string?

Answer (score 23):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, as an alternative to regex solutions, it's also possible to pattern match a `String` by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
"one493two483three" match { case s"${x}two${y}three" => y }
// String = "483"
```

Or even:

```
val s"${x}two${y}three" = "one493two483three"
// x: String = one493
// y: String = 483
```

If you expect non matching input, you can add a default pattern guard:

```
"one493deux483three" match {
  case s"${x}two${y}three" => y
  case _                   => "no match"
}
// String = "no match"
```

Answer (score 16):

You want to look at `group(1)`, you're currently looking at `group(0)`, which is "the entire matched string".

See [this regex tutorial](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/01/regular-expression-1-basics-and.html).

Comment: can you illustrate on the input I provided? I tried to call `group(1)` on what's returned by findAllIn but I get an IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 5):

```
def extractFileNameFromHttpFilePathExpression(expr: String) = {
//define regex
val regex = "http4.*\\/(\\w+.(xlsx|xls|zip))$".r
// findFirstMatchIn/findAllMatchIn returns Option[Match] and Match has methods to access capture groups.
regex.findFirstMatchIn(expr) match {
  case Some(i) => i.group(1)
  case None => "regex_error"
}
}
extractFileNameFromHttpFilePathExpression(
    "http4://testing.bbmkl.com/document/sth1234.zip")
```