# Selectively uppercasing a string

Tags: regex, scala, replaceall

I have a string with some XML tags in it, like:

```
"hello <b>world</b> and <i>everyone</i>"
```

Is there a good Scala/functional way of uppercasing the words, but not the tags, so that it looks like:

```
"HELLO <b>WORLD<b> AND <i>EVERYONE</i>"
```

Comment: This regex should match the text you want: (?<!<|\/>)\w+(?!>).  You can then set the matching text to uppercase.  I'm not familiar with scala though.

Comment: Are the `&lt;` really part of your string, or is it a simple copy+paste error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use *dustmouse*'s regex to replace all the text in/outside XML tags with [`Regex.replaceAllIn`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex). We can get the matched text with [`Regex.Match.matched`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex$$Match) which then can easily be uppercased using `toUpperCase`.

```
val xmlText = """(?<!<|<\/)\b\w+(?!>)""".r

val string = "hello <b>world</b> and <i>everyone</i>"
xmlText.replaceAllIn(string, _.matched.toUpperCase)
// String = HELLO <b>WORLD</b> AND <i>EVERYONE</i>

val string2 = "<h1>>hello</h1> <span>world</span> and <span><i>everyone</i>"
xmlText.replaceAllIn(string2, _.matched.toUpperCase)
// String = <h1>>HELLO</h1> <span>WORLD</span> AND <span><i>EVERYONE</i>
```

Using *dustmouse*'s updated regex :

```
val xmlText = """(?:<[^<>]+>\s*)(\w+)""".r

val string3 = """<h1>>hello</h1> <span id="test">world</span>"""
xmlText.replaceAllIn(string3, m => 
  m.group(0).dropRight(m.group(1).length) + m.group(1).toUpperCase)
// String = <h1>>hello</h1> <span id="test">WORLD</span>
```

Comment: Needs work. `<h1>>hello</h1> <span>world</span> and <span><i>everyone</i></span>` results in `<h1>>HELLO</H1> <sPAn>WORLD</SPAn> AND <sPAn><i>EVERYONE</i></SPAn>`

Comment: @dustmouse That works for Pauls case, but if we add attributes (`<span id="test">`), this also does not work correctly, but the OP has not specified attributes, so it is definitely an improvement.

Comment: How about this: (?:<[^<>]+>\s*)(\w+).  https://regex101.com/r/bU1cD9/4.  As long as scala can work with capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, how about this.  It just prints the results, and takes into consideration some of the scenarios brought up by others.  Not sure how to capitalize the output without mercilessly poaching from Peter's answer:

```
val string = "<h1 id=\"test\">hello</h1> <span>world</span> and <span><i>everyone</i></span>"
val pattern = """(?:<[^<>]+>\s*)(\w+)""".r

pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
    m => println(m.group(1))
}
```

The main thing here is that it is extracting the correct capture group.

Working example: http://ideone.com/2qlwoP

Also need to give credit to the answer here for getting capture groups in scala: [Scala capture group using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050907/scala-capture-group-using-regex)