# Scala regex: get last number of string

Tags: regex, scala

So i have this `String`:

```
val line = "Displaying elements 1 - 4 of 4 in total"
```

And i want to to parse the total amount: `4` in this case.

This is what i have try:

```
val line = "Displaying elements 1 - 4 of 4 in total"
val pattern = "\\d".r
println(pattern.findAllMatchIn(line))
```

Comment: `line.split(' ')(6)`  'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems.'' - Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 3):

The [regex API in Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.3/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) only provides a method to get the *first* match ([`findFirstIn`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.3/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findFirstIn(source:CharSequence):Option[String])) or *all* matches ([`findAllIn`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.3/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findAllIn(source:CharSequence):scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator)), but not the *last* match. Most languages have a similar set of regex methods because to get the last regex match you may easily get all matches but only refer to the last one.

Same in Scala:

```
val line = "Displaying invoices 1 - 4 of 9 in total"
val pattern = """\d+""".r
println(pattern.findAllIn(line).toList.last)
// => 9
```

**As an alternative**, for the current scenario, you may also use

```
val line = "Displaying invoices 1 - 4 of 4 in total"
val pattern = """\d+(?=\s*in total)""".r
println(pattern.findFirstIn(line))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/rXzbpU).

The `\d+(?=\s*in total)` pattern will find 1 or more digits (`\d+`) that are followed with 0+ whitespaces and `in total` substring (see the positive lookahead `(?=\s*in total)`).

Answer (score 2):

You can let [greed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) eat up the line until last number.

```
.*\b(\d+)
```

- `.*` matches greedily any amount of any character until `\b` a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(\d+)` [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) one or more [`\d`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) digits by [`group(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3051206/5527985)

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iV0gE7/2)

If you expect decimal number, add a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and modify to [`.*\b(?<![.,])(\d[\d.,]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/wU1mX3/1)