# Split string based on parantheses

Tags: java, regex, scala, split

I'm writing Scala code which splits a line based on a colon (:). 
Example, for an input which looked like:

```
sparker0i@outlook.com : password
```

I was doing `line.split(" : ")` (which is essentially Java) and printing the email and the password on Console.

Now my requirement has changed and now a line will look like:

```
(sparker0i@outlook.com,sparker0i) : password
```

I want to individually print the **email**, **username** and **password** separately.

I've tried Regex by first trying to split the parantheses, but that didn't work because it is not correct (`val lt = line.split("[\\\\(||//)]")`). Please guide me with the correct regex/split logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a scala user, but instead of split, I think you can use Pattern and matcher to extract this info, your regex can use groups like:

```
\((.*?),(.*?)\) : (.*)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFCq5Q/1)

Then you can extract group 1 for email, group 2 for username and the 3rd group for password.

```
val input = "(sparker0i@outlook.com,sparker0i) : password"
val pattern = """\((.*?),(.*?)\) : (.*)""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
   m => println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2) + " " + m.group(3))
}
```

---

Credit for this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3051206/5558072

Comment: You can also use `input match { case pattern(email, name, password) => /* ... */ }` to match.

Answer (score 1):

The regex I would use:

```
\((.*?),([^)]+)\) : (.+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P5wWCw/2/)

```
\(        # Matches (
(         # Start of capture group 1
   (.*?)  # Capture 0 or more characters until ...
)         # End of capture group 1
,         # matches ,
(         # start of capture group 2
   [^)]+  # captures one or more characters that are not a )
)         # end of capture group 2
\)        # Matches )
 :        # matches ' : '
(         # start of capture group 3
   (.+)   # matches rest of string
)         # end of capture group 3
```

The Java implementation would be:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s =  "(sparker0i@outlook.com,sparker0i) : password";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?),([^)]+)\\) : (.+)");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
            System.out.println(m.group(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
sparker0i@outlook.com
sparker0i
password
```

[Java Demo](https://ideone.com/8Ebl1J)

Answer (score 1):

In scala 2.13, there is a simple solution without regrex:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_222).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val input = "(sparker0i@outlook.com,sparker0i) : password"
input: String = (sparker0i@outlook.com,sparker0i) : password

scala> val s"($mail,$user) : $pwd" = input
mail: String = sparker0i@outlook.com
user: String = sparker0i
pwd: String = password
```

Answer (score 0):

**this is without doing much change**

```
    String s =  "(sparker0i@outlook.com,sparker0i) : password";
    // do whatever you were doing 
    String[] sArr = s.split(":");
    sArr[0] = sArr[0].replaceAll("[(|)]","");  // just replace those parenthesis with empty string
    System.out.println(sArr[0] + " " + sArr[1]);
```

**Output**

```
sparker0i@outlook.com,sparker0i   password
```